# Python: Duda Lista como output

Tags: python, lista

Escribo ya que tengo un ejercicio de listas en Python y no se exactamente como resolverlo, el programa debe leer estudiantes (nombre, apellido y nota, estos deben ingresarse separados por coma; y cada estudiante separado por slash) y al final imprimir como strings los estudiantes de la lista de Aprobados y los estudiantes de la lista Reprobados.

Ahora bien el código que tengo es este.

```
datos=input("Ingresa los datos de la persona:Nombre,Apellido y Nota(número) separado por coma y cada persona separada por slash: \n")
lista=datos.split("/")
largo=len(lista)
#print(lista)
reprobado=[]
aprobado=[]

for i in range(largo):
    lista[i]=lista[i].split(",")
#asdasd,asdprint(lista)

for i in lista:
    if int(i[2]) <= 4:
        reprobado.append(i)
    else:
        aprobado.append(i)


print("Los estudiantes aprobados son:")
print(aprobado)
print("Los estudiantes reprobados son:")
print(reprobado)
```

Y no se como llegar al resultado deseado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código debe ir _en la pregunta misma_. Tanto el código como las salidas y los mensajes de error deben ir _como texto, con formato_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se resuelve recorriendo las dos listas nuevamente, e imprimir cada elemento de la lista en lugar de imprimir la lista completa nuevamente. Además debes asegurarte de imprimir lo que necesites de cada alumno, por lo que organizar tu información ayudará a que sea más fácil imprimirla después. En mi código, guardo la información que necesito en una tupla, para acceder a los datos ya procesados y que este listos para imprimir.

```
input_string = "Pedro, López, 7/Laura, González, 3/Daniela, Muñoz, 5/Carlos, Galván, 3"

def clasificar_estudiantes(input: str):
    aprobados = []
    reprobados = []
    estudiantes = input.split('/')
    
    for estudiante in estudiantes:
        estudiante_datos = estudiante.split(',')
        calificacion = int(estudiante_datos[-1])

        # Une en un string el nombre del alumno. Como el último indice de los datos es la calificación, lo excluimos.
        nombre_estudiante = " ".join(estudiante_datos[:-1])
        tupla_estudiante = (nombre_estudiante, estudiante_datos[-1])
        
        if calificacion >= 6:
            aprobados.append(tupla_estudiante)
        else:
            reprobados.append(tupla_estudiante)

    return aprobados, reprobados

def imprime_lista_estudiantes(lista, tipo = "aprobados"):
    print("La lista de estudiantes " + tipo + " son:")

    for estudiante_tupla in lista:
        print(estudiante_tupla[0] + " con nota " + estudiante_tupla[1])


aprobados, reprobados = clasificar_estudiantes(input_string)
imprime_lista_estudiantes(aprobados, "aprobados")
print("\n----------------------\n")
imprime_lista_estudiantes(reprobados, "reprobados")
```

En mi código anterior, el programa imprime lo siguiente:

```
La lista de estudiantes aprobados son:
Pedro  López con nota  7

----------------------

La lista de estudiantes reprobados son:
Laura  González con nota  3
Daniela  Muñoz con nota  5
Carlos  Galván con nota  3
```

Lo cual es similar a lo que buscas lograr.

Comment: Agradecido por la asistencia Jacobo, lo de usar una DEF con su Return no lo había pensado.